# My Australian visa has a "Must Not Arrive After" date, but not a "Must Not Arrive Before" date. Does this mean I can arrive immediately?

Tags: visa, australia

I've been granted a Temporary Activity (subclass 408) visa from Australia, but confusingly the document says nothing about what's the earliest date I can actually arrive to the country. There is a "**Must Not Arrive After**" date and a "**Stay Period**" of "**13 month(s) from the date of first arrival**".

But what is the earliest date I can actually arrive to the country? Could I go immediately, if I wanted? The contract for the 408 Activity position doesn't begin until July 10th, so I'm confused if I can arrive to the country beforehand.

*NB: I'm writing this question for a friend. I'm using the personal pronoun for easier readability.*

Comment: I don't know anything about Australian law (hence a comment) but your interpretation sounds correct and not that surprising to me. That's the way many long-term visas work.

Comment: The only thing I could find was, "If your Temporary Activity visa (subclass 408) is granted when you are outside Australia, the stay period starts from the day that you first enter Australia as the holder of this visa."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Section 68 of the *Migration Act 1958*](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/C2017C00068/Html/Volume_1#_Toc476579889) sets out when a visa is in effect:

> (1)  Subject to subsection (2), a visa has effect as soon as it is granted.
>
> (2)  A visa may provide that it comes into effect at the beginning of a day, being a day after its grant:
>
> (a)  specified in the visa; or
>
> (b)  when an event, specified in the visa, happens.
>
> ...

So unless otherwise specified in the visa grant notice, you can enter Australia immediately.